# Snmp - clear portsecurity sticky address in cisco

Tags: cisco, snmp

i am writing script to clear particular sticky mac address.
I have fount that snmp oid is:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.315.1.2.1.1.14
```

it can take following values:

```
0:done
1:dynamic
2:static
3:sticky
4:all
```

So i guess that i can remove all sticky mac adresses from particular interface but how to remove only one mac ?

There is a command in ios:

```
clear port-security sticky address aaa.bbb.ccc
```

Is it possible to do it in snmp or just clear all sticky on IF

I am using snmpset in linux - to set values.